# formData (id +string) not working

Tags: javascript, php, html

my javascript:

```
function updatedata(str){

    var id = str;

    var formData= new FormData($('#registrationform'+str)[0]);//serialize all form data including the file data

    $.ajax({
        url: "update_registration.php?id="+id,//php page to process all form data
        type: 'POST',
        data: formData,
        async: false,
        success: function (data) {
        $('#info2').html(data);//div where data are displayed
        viewdata(); 
        },
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false
    });

    return false;
}
```

my html page:

```
    <table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
    <thead>
    <tr>
      <th style="text-align:center; border-bottom:hidden" valign="top" class="info"><span class="info" style="text-align:center">Reg No.</span></th>
      <th style="text-align:center; border-bottom:hidden" valign="top" class="info"><span class="info" style="text-align:center">Picture</span></th>
      <th style="text-align:center; border-bottom:hidden" valign="top" class="info"><span class="info" style="text-align:center">Course</span></th>
      <th style="text-align:center; border-bottom:hidden" valign="top" class="info">Class Code</th>
      <th colspan="2" style="text-align:center; border-bottom:hidden" valign="top" class="info"><span class="info" style="text-align:center">Course Schedule </span></th>
      <th colspan="3" style="text-align:center; border-bottom:hidden" valign="top" class="info"><span class="info" style="text-align:center">Full Name</span></th>
      <th style="text-align:center; border-bottom:hidden" valign="top" class="info"><span class="info" style="text-align:center">Municipality/City</span></th>
      <th style="text-align:center; border-bottom:hidden" valign="top" class="info"><span class="info" style="text-align:center">Company Sponsor</span></th>
      <th style="text-align:center; border-bottom:hidden" valign="top" class="info"><span class="info" style="text-align:center">Date Of Registration</span></th>
      <th style="text-align:center; border-bottom:hidden" valign="top" class="info"><span class="info" style="text-align:center">Approved By</span></th>
      <th colspan="2" style="text-align:center; border-bottom:hidden" valign="top" class="info"><span class="info" style="text-align:center">Action</span></th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <?php

    include "connect_database.php";

    $fetchquery9 = "SELECT * FROM `registration`"; 
    $fetch9 = mysqli_query($conn, $fetchquery9);

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($fetch9)) 
    {

    ?>

    <tr style="text-align:center">
    <td><?php echo $row['reg_number']; ?></td>
    <?php echo "<td>".'<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode( $row['picture'] ).'" />'." </td>";?>
    <td><?php echo $row['course']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['class_code']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['start_date_reg']; ?></td><td><?php echo $row['end_date_reg']; ?></td>
    <td style="border-right:hidden"><?php echo $row['surname']; ?></td>
    <td style="border-right:hidden"><?php echo $row['first_name']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['middle_name']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['municipality_city']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['company_sponsor']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['date_of_reg']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['approved_by']; ?></td>



    <td style="border-right:hidden"><a class="btn btn-warning btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" data-target="#myModal<?php echo $row['reg_number']; ?>"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></span></a></td>
    <td><a class="btn btn-danger btn-sm data-toggle=confirmation data-popout=true"   onclick="deletedata('<?php echo $row['reg_number']; ?>')"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" aria-hidden="true"></span></a></td>


    <!-- Modal -->

    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal<?php echo $row['reg_number']; ?>" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel<?php echo $row['reg_number']; ?>" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" style="width:80%" >
    <div class="modal-content">

    <div class="modal-header">      
    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel<?php echo $row['reg_number']; ?>">Edit Data</h4>
    </div>

    <br/>
    <div id="info3" align="center"></div>
    <br/>

    <div class="modal-body">
    <form id="registrationform<?php echo $row['reg_number']; ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <div class="row">

    <div class="col-md-8">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="form-group">        
    <img  id="image<?php echo $row['reg_number']; ?>" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,<?php echo base64_encode($row['picture']); ?>" alt="Click to Upload an Image" style="max-height:192px; max-width:192px; min-height:192px; max-width:192px; width:192px; height:192px; text-align:center; line-height:192px; vertical-align:central" onClick="uploadedit('<?php echo $row['reg_number']; ?>')"/>
    <input type="file"  name="file" id="file<?php echo $row['reg_number']; ?>" style="display:none" onchange="previewedit('<?php echo $row['reg_number']; ?>');" accept="image/jpeg,image/x-png" class="form-control"/>
    </div>
    </div>

    </div>

    <div class="row">

    <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="col-md-2">
    <div class="form-group">
    <label for="registrationno">Registration No.</label> 
    <input  type="number" min="0" id="registrationno<?php echo $row['reg_number']; ?>"  value="<?php echo $row['reg_number']; ?>" name="registrationno" class="form-control">
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>  
    </div>

    <input type="hidden" id="hidden3<?php echo $row['reg_number']; ?>"  value="<?php echo $row['reg_number']; ?>" name="hidden3" class="form-control">

    <div class="row">

    <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="form-group">
    <label for="course">Course</label>  
    <select  type="text" id="course<?php echo $row['reg_number']; ?>"  value="<?php echo $row['course']; ?>" onchange="getfeex('<?php echo $row['reg_number']; ?>');" name="course" class="form-control">
    <option value="<?php echo $row['course']; ?>"><?php echo $row['course']; ?></option>
    <?php 
    include "connect_database.php";
    $fetchquery = "SELECT `course_description` FROM `list_of_courses` ORDER BY `course_description`";
    $fetch = mysqli_query($conn, $fetchquery);
    while ($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($fetch))
    {
    echo "<option value=\"".$rows['course_description']."\">".$rows['course_description']."</option>";
    }
    ?>
    </select>
    </div>
    </div>


    <input type="hidden" id="hidden2<?php echo $row['reg_number']; ?>"  value="<?php echo $row['course']; ?>" name="hidden2" class="form-control">

    <div class="col-md-4">

    <div class="col-md-9">
    <div class="form-group">
    <label for="classcode">Class Code</label>  
    <input type="text" id="classcode<?php echo $row['reg_number']; ?>" value="<?php echo $row['class_code']; ?>" name="classcode" class="form-control">
    </div>
    </div>




    <div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="form-group">
    <a href="class_list_form.php"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt"></span> view class list</a>
    </div>
    </div>

    </div>      

    <input type="hidden" id="hidden<?php echo $row['reg_number']; ?>" value="<?php echo $row['class_code']; ?>" name="hidden" class="form-control">


    <div class="col-md-4">  
    <div class="form-group">
    <label for="dateofregistration">Date of Registration</label>  
    <input  type="date" id="dateofregistration<?php echo $row['reg_number']; ?>" value="<?php echo $row['date_of_reg']; ?>" name="dateofregistration" class="form-control" readonly>
    </div>
    </div>

    </div>

    <div class="row">

    <div class="col-md-8">
    <div class="form-group">
    <label for="companysponsor">Company Sponsor</label>  
    <input type="text" id="companysponsor<?php echo $row['reg_number']; ?>" value="<?php echo $row['company_sponsor']; ?>" name="companysponsor" class="form-control">
    </div>
    </div>


    <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="form-group">
    <label for="telno">Tel No.</label>  
    <input type="number" min="0" id="telno<?php echo $row['reg_number']; ?>" value="<?php echo $row['tel_no']; ?>" name="telno" class="form-control">    
    </div>
    </div>

    </div>

    <div class="row">

    <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="form-group">        
    <label for="surname">Surname</label>
    <input type="text" id="surname<?php echo $row['reg_number']; ?>" value="<?php echo $row['surname']; ?>" name="surname" class="form-control">
    </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="form-group">
    <label for="firstname">First Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname<?php echo $row['reg_number']; ?>" value="<?php echo $row['first_name']; ?>" class="form-control">
    </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="form-group">    
    <label for="middlename">Middle Name</label>
    <input type="text"  id="middlename<?php echo $row['reg_number']; ?>" value="<?php echo $row['middle_name']; ?>" name="middlename" class="form-control">
    </div>
    </div>

    </div>

    <div class="row">

    <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="form-group">    
    <label for="email">Email</label>
    <input type="email"  id="email<?php echo $row['reg_number']; ?>" value="<?php echo $row['email']; ?>" name="email" class="form-control">
    </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="form-group">    
    <label for="cellphone">Cellphone No.</label>
    <input type="number" min="0" id="cellphone<?php echo $row['reg_number']; ?>" value="<?php echo $row['cellphone']; ?>" name="cellphone" class="form-control">
    </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="form-group">    
    <label for="landline">Landline</label>
    <input type="number" min="0" id="landline<?php echo $row['reg_number']; ?>" value="<?php echo $row['land_line']; ?>" name="landline" class="form-control">
    </div>
    </div>

    </div>

    <div class="row">

    <div class="col-md-8">
    <div class="form-group">    
    <label for="street">Street No. and Street Name</label>
    <input type="number" min="0" id="street<?php echo $row['reg_number']; ?>" value="<?php echo $row['st_no_and_st_name']; ?>" name="street" class="form-control">
    </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="form-group">    
    <label for="barangay">Barangay</label>
    <input type="text"  id="barangay<?php echo $row['reg_number']; ?>" value="<?php echo $row['brgy']; ?>" name="barangay" class="form-control">
    </div>
    </div>

    </div>

    <div class="row">

    <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="form-group">    
    <label for="municipalitycity">Municipality/City</label>
    <input type="text"  id="municipalitycity<?php echo $row['reg_number']; ?>" value="<?php echo $row['municipality_city']; ?>" name="municipalitycity" class="form-control">
    </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="form-group">    
    <label for="district">District</label>
    <input type="text" id="district<?php echo $row['reg_number']; ?>" value="<?php echo $row['district']; ?>" name="district" class="form-control">
    </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="form-group">    
    <label for="province">Province</label>
    <input type="text" id="province<?php echo $row['reg_number']; ?>" value="<?php echo $row['province']; ?>" name="province" class="form-control">
    </div>
    </div>

    </div>

    <div class="row">

    <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="form-group">
    <label for="nationality">Nationality</label>
    <input type="text"  id="nationality<?php echo $row['reg_number']; ?>" value="<?php echo $row['nationality']; ?>" name="nationality" class="form-control">
    </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="form-group">
    <label for="birthplace">Birthplace</label>
    <input type="text"  id="birthplace<?php echo $row['reg_number']; ?>" value="<?php echo $row['birthplace']; ?>" name="birthplace" class="form-control">
    </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-2">
    <div class="form-group">
    <label for="dateofbirth">Date of Birth</label>
    <input type="date" id="dateofbirth<?php echo $row['reg_number']; ?>" value="<?php echo $row['date_of_birth']; ?>" name="dateofbirth" class="form-control">
    </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-2">
    <div class="form-group">
    <label for="sex">Gender</label>
    <select  name="sex" id="sex<?php echo $row['reg_number']; ?>" value="<?php echo $row['sex']; ?>" class="form-control">
    <option value="<?php echo $row['reg_number']; ?>"><?php echo $row['sex']; ?></option>
    <option value="Male">Male</option>
    <option value="Female">Female</option>
    </select>
    </div>
    </div>

    </div>

    <div class="row">

    <div class="col-md-2">
    <div class="form-group">
    <label for="age">Age</label>
    <input type="number" min="0" id="age<?php echo $row['reg_number']; ?>" value="<?php echo $row['age']; ?>" name="age" class="form-control">
    </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-2">
    <div class="form-group">
    <label for="civilstatus">Civil Status</label>
    <select type="text"  id="civilstatus<?php echo $row['reg_number']; ?>" value="<?php echo $row['civil_status']; ?>" name="civilstatus" class="form-control">
    <option value="<?php echo $row['reg_number']; ?>"><?php echo $row['civil_status']; ?></option>
    <option value="Single">Single</option>
    <option value="Married">Married</option>
    <option value="Divorced">Divorced</option>
    <option value="Widowed">Widowed</option>
    </select>
    </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4">
     <div class="form-group">   
    <label for="persontocontact">Person to contact incase of emergency</label>
    <input type="text" id="persontocontact<?php echo $row['reg_number']; ?>" value="<?php echo $row['person_to_contact']; ?>" name="persontocontact" class="form-control">
    </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4">
     <div class="form-group">   
    <label for="contactno">Contact No.</label>
    <input type="number" min="0" id="contactno<?php echo $row['reg_number']; ?>" value="<?php echo $row['contactno']; ?>" name="contactno" class="form-control">
    </div>
    </div>

    </div>

    <div class="row">

    <div class="col-md-4">
     <div class="form-group">   
    <label for="educationalattainment">Educational Attainment</label>
    <input type="text" id="educationalattainment<?php echo $row['reg_number']; ?>" value="<?php echo $row['highest_educational_attainment']; ?>" name="educationalattainment" class="form-control">
    </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="form-group">    
    <label for="school">School/Training Center</label>
    <input type="text" id="school<?php echo $row['reg_number']; ?>" value="<?php echo $row['school']; ?>" name="school" class="form-control">
    </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="form-group">
    <label for="coursedegree">Course/Degree</label>
    <input type="text"  id="coursedegree<?php echo $row['reg_number']; ?>" value="<?php echo $row['course_degree']; ?>" name="coursedegree" class="form-control">
    </div>
    </div>

    </div>


    <div class="row">

    <div class="col-md-12">
    <p class="col-md-12" style="font-size:x-large; color:#009 ;font-weight:bold!important">COURSES TAKEN (Kitchen/Galley Related Trainings)</p>
    </div>

    </div>  

    <div class="row"> 

    <div class="col-md-2">
    <div class="form-group">
    <label>Tittle of Course</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="titleofcourse1<?php echo $row['reg_number']; ?>" value="<?php echo $row['title_of_course1']; ?>" name="titleofcourse1"/><br>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="titleofcourse2<?php echo $row['reg_number']; ?>" value="<?php echo $row['title_of_course2']; ?>" name="titleofcourse2"/><br>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="titleofcourse3<?php echo $row['reg_number']; ?>" value="<?php echo $row['title_of_course3']; ?>" name="titleofcourse3"/><br>
    </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-2">
    <div class="form-group">
    <label>Month and Year Taken</label>
    <input type="month" class="form-control" id="yeartaken1<?php echo $row['reg_number']; ?>" value="<?php echo $row['year_taken1']; ?>" name="yeartaken1"/><br>
    <input type="month" class="form-control" id="yeartaken2<?php echo $row['reg_number']; ?>" value="<?php echo $row['year_taken2']; ?>" name="yeartaken2"/><br>
    <input type="month" class="form-control" id="yeartaken3<?php echo $row['reg_number']; ?>" value="<?php echo $row['year_taken3']; ?>" name="yeartaken3"/><br>
    </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="form-group">
    <label>School Training Center</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="trainingcenter1<?php echo $row['reg_number']; ?>" value="<?php echo $row['school_training_center1']; ?>" name="trainingcenter1"/><br>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="trainingcenter2<?php echo $row['reg_number']; ?>" value="<?php echo $row['school_training_center2']; ?>" name="trainingcenter2"/><br>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="trainingcenter3<?php echo $row['reg_number']; ?>" value="<?php echo $row['school_training_center3']; ?>" name="trainingcenter3"/><br>
    </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="form-group">
    <label>Certificates Achieved</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="certifications1<?php echo $row['reg_number']; ?>" value="<?php echo $row['certifications_achieved1']; ?>" name="certifications1"/><br>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="certifications2<?php echo $row['reg_number']; ?>" value="<?php echo $row['certifications_achieved2']; ?>" name="certifications2"/><br>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="certifications3<?php echo $row['reg_number']; ?>" value="<?php echo $row['certifications_achieved3']; ?>" name="certifications3"/><br>
    </div>
    </div>

    </div>

    <div class="row">

    <div class="col-md-12" align="center">
    <p class="col-md-12" style="font-size:x-large; color:#009 ;font-weight:bold!important">ACCOUNTING</p>
    </div>

    </div>

    <div class="row">

    <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="col-md-6">
    <p>Approved by</p><input type="text" class="form-control" id="name<?php echo $row['reg_number']; ?>" value="<?php echo $row['approved_by']; ?>" name="name" readonly/>
    </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-2">
    <div class="form-group">

    <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="form-group">
    <input type="radio" name="choice" value="Cash" id="cash" onChange="radiobutton1x('<?php echo $row['reg_number']; ?>');">
    <label for="cashamount">Cash</label>
    <input type="number" min="0" class="form-control" name="cashamount" id="cashamount<?php echo $row['reg_number']; ?>" value="<?php echo $row['amount_cash']; ?>" onchange="x('<?php echo $row['reg_number']; ?>');" readonly/>
    </div>
    </div>

    </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-2">
    <div class="form-group">

    <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="form-group">
    <input type="radio" name="choice" value="Check" id="check" onChange="radiobutton2x('<?php echo $row['reg_number']; ?>');">
    <label for="check_no">Check No.</label>
    <input type="number" min="0" class="form-control" name="check_no" id="check_no<?php echo $row['reg_number']; ?>" value="<?php echo $row['check_no']; ?>" readonly/>
    </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="form-group">
    <label for="bank">Bank</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="bank<?php echo $row['reg_number']; ?>" value="<?php echo $row['bank']; ?>" name="bank" readonly/>
    </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="form-group">
    <label for="check_amount">Amount</label>
    <input type="number" min="0" class="form-control" id="checkamount<?php echo $row['reg_number']; ?>" value="<?php echo $row['amount_check']; ?>" name="checkamount" onchange="y('<?php echo $row['reg_number']; ?>');" readonly/>
    </div>
    </div>

    </div>
    </div>


    <div class="col-md-2">
    <div class="form-group">

    <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="form-group">
    <input type="radio" name="choice" value="Card" id="cards" onChange="radiobutton3x('<?php echo $row['reg_number']; ?>');">
    <label for="card">Card</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="card" id="card<?php echo $row['reg_number']; ?>" value="<?php echo $row['card']; ?>" readonly/>
    </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="form-group">
    <label>Type</label>
    <input type="type" class="form-control" id="cardtype<?php echo $row['reg_number']; ?>" value="<?php echo $row['card_type']; ?>" name="cardtype" readonly/>
    </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="form-group">
    <label>Appr Code</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="appr_code<?php echo $row['reg_number']; ?>" value="<?php echo $row['appr_code']; ?>" name="appr_code" readonly/>
    </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="form-group">
    <label for="card_amount">Amount</label>
    <input type="number" min"0" class="form-control" id="card_amount<?php echo $row['reg_number']; ?>" value="<?php echo $row['amount_card']; ?>" name="card_amount" onchange="z('<?php echo $row['reg_number']; ?>');" readonly/>
    </div>
    </div>

    </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-2">
    <div class="form-group">

    <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="form-group">
    <label for="charge">Charge</label>
    <select type="text" class="form-control" id="charge<?php echo $row['reg_number']; ?>" value="<?php echo $row['charge']; ?>" name="charge">
    <option value="<?php echo $row['reg_number']; ?>"><?php echo $row['charge']; ?></option>
    <option value="Personal">Personal</option>
    <option value="Company">Company</option>
    </select>
    </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="form-group">
    <label for="modeofpayment">Payment</label>
    <select type="text" class="form-control" id="modeofpayment<?php echo $row['reg_number']; ?>" value="<?php echo $row['mode_of_payment']; ?>" name="modeofpayment">
    <option value="<?php echo $row['reg_number']; ?>"><?php echo $row['mode_of_payment']; ?></option>
    <option value="Full">Full</option>
    <option value="Partial">Partial</option>
    </select>
    </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="form-group">
    <label>Tuition</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="tuition<?php echo $row['reg_number']; ?>" value="<?php echo $row['tuition']; ?>" name="tuition"/>
    </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="form-group">
    <label for="balance">Balance</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="balance<?php echo $row['reg_number']; ?>" value="<?php echo $row['balance']; ?>" name="balance" />
    </div>
    </div>

    </div>
    </div>

    </div>

    </form>
    </div>


    <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" onclick="viewdata();">Close</button>
    <button type="button" onclick="updatedata('<?php echo $row['reg_number']; ?>')" class="btn btn-primary">Update</button>
    </div>

    </div>
    </div>
    </div>


    </td>
    </tr>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
    </tbody>
    </table>
```

php

```
     <?php print_r($_POST);; print_r($_FILES) ?> //print all post
```

I want to see all form data display in array as result of new formData but it only display Array ( ) nothing more. 
I'm guessing that it can't find the the form element because of the +str on the form id
What should i change to see all form in array?

Comment: `var formData = $('#registrationform'+str).serialize();`

Comment: what about the input file? does .serialize include input file?

Comment: No -> [`$.serialize()`](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/)

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<form action="." method="post" id="form">
    <input type="text" name="name" value="Ajay">
    <input type="text" name="location" value="Chennai">
    <button id="button">Button</button>
</form>
<div class="frmData">POST Values printed here..</div>
```

jQuery:
This function should be inside the document ready function.

```
$('#button').click(function(){
    var frmData = $('#form').serialize();
    $('.frmData').html(frmData);
});
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion but i believe .serialize()  does not include input type=file..my form have a input type=file..so i use new formData

Answer (score 0):

found an alternative solution on this

```
function updatedata(str){

 var id = str;
 var registrationno = $('#registrationno'+str).val();
 var course = $('#course'+str).val();
 var classcode = $('#classcode'+str).val();
 var dateofregistration = $('#dateofregistration'+str).val();
 var companysponsor = $('#companysponsor'+str).val();
 var telno = $('#telno'+str).val();
 var surname = $('#surname'+str).val();
 var firstname = $('#firstname'+str).val();
 var middlename = $('#middlename'+str).val();
 var email = $('#email'+str).val();
 var cellphone = $('#cellphone'+str).val();
 var landline = $('#landline'+str).val();
 var street = $('#street'+str).val();
 var barangay = $('#barangay'+str).val();
 var municipalitycity = $('#municipalitycity'+str).val();
 var district = $('#district'+str).val();
 var province = $('#province'+str).val();
 var nationality = $('#nationality'+str).val();
 var birthplace = $('#birthplace'+str).val();
 var dateofbirth = $('#dateofbirth'+str).val();
 var sex = $('#sex'+str).val();
 var age = $('#age'+str).val();
 var civilstatus = $('#civilstatus'+str).val();
 var persontocontact = $('#persontocontact'+str).val();
 var contactno = $('#contactno'+str).val();
 var educationalattainment = $('#educationalattainment'+str).val();
 var school = $('#school'+str).val();
 var coursedegree = $('#coursedegree'+str).val();
 var nameofcompany1 = $('#nameofcompany1'+str).val();
 var nameofcompany2 = $('#nameofcompany2'+str).val();
 var nameofcompany3 = $('#nameofcompany3'+str).val();
 var typeofcompany1 = $('#typeofcompany1'+str).val();
 var typeofcompany2 = $('#typeofcompany2'+str).val();
 var typeofcompany3 = $('#typeofcompany3'+str).val();
 var datefrom1 = $('#datefrom1'+str).val();
 var datefrom2 = $('#datefrom2'+str).val();
 var datefrom3 = $('#datefrom3'+str).val();
 var dateto1 = $('#dateto1'+str).val();
 var dateto2 = $('#dateto2'+str).val();
 var dateto3 = $('#dateto3'+str).val();
 var position1 = $('#position1'+str).val();
 var position2 = $('#position2'+str).val();
 var position3 = $('#position3'+str).val();
 var titleofcourse1 = $('#titleofcourse1'+str).val();
 var titleofcourse2 = $('#titleofcourse2'+str).val();
 var titleofcourse3 = $('#titleofcourse3'+str).val();
 var yeartaken1 = $('#yeartaken1'+str).val();
 var yeartaken2 = $('#yeartaken2'+str).val();
 var yeartaken3 = $('#yeartaken3'+str).val();
 var trainingcenter1 = $('#trainingcenter1'+str).val();
 var trainingcenter2 = $('#trainingcenter2'+str).val();
 var trainingcenter3 = $('#trainingcenter3'+str).val();
 var certifications1 = $('#certifications1'+str).val();
 var certifications2 = $('#certifications2'+str).val();
 var certifications3 = $('#certifications3'+str).val();
 var cashamount = $('#cashamount'+str).val();
 var charge = $('#charge'+str).val();
 var modeofpayment = $('#modeofpayment'+str).val();
 var tuition = $('#tuition'+str).val();
 var balance = $('#balance'+str).val();
 var card = $('#card').val();
 var cardtype = $('#cardtype'+str).val();
 var card_amount = $('#card_amount'+str).val();
 var appr_code = $('#appr_code'+str).val();
 var bank = $('#bank'+str).val();
 var check_no = $('#check_no'+str).val();
 var checkamount = $('#checkamount'+str).val();
 var hidden = $('#hidden'+str).val();
 var hidden2 = $('#hidden2'+str).val();
 var hidden3 = $('#hidden3'+str).val();

     var $form    = $('#myModal'+str),
            formData = new FormData(),

            files    = $form.find('[name="file"]')[0].files;

        $.each(files, function(i, file) {
            // Prefix the name of uploaded files with "uploadedFiles-"
            // Of course, you can change it to any string
            formData.append('file', file);
        });


$.ajax({
    url: "update_registration.php?registrationno="+registrationno+"&course="+course+"&classcode="+classcode+"&dateofregistration="+dateofregistration+"&companysponsor="+companysponsor+"&telno="+telno+"&surname="+surname+"&firstname="+firstname+"&middlename="+middlename+"&email="+email+"&cellphone="+cellphone+"&landline="+landline+"&street="+street+"&barangay="+barangay+"&municipalitycity="+municipalitycity+"&district="+district+"&province="+province+"&nationality="+nationality+"&birthplace="+birthplace+"&dateofbirth="+dateofbirth+"&sex="+sex+"&age="+age+"&civilstatus="+civilstatus+"&persontocontact="+persontocontact+"&contactno="+contactno+"&educationalattainment="+educationalattainment+"&school="+school+"&coursedegree="+coursedegree+"&nameofcompany1="+nameofcompany1+"&nameofcompany2="+nameofcompany2+"&nameofcompany3="+nameofcompany3+"&typeofcompany1="+typeofcompany1+"&typeofcompany2="+typeofcompany2+"&typeofcompany3="+typeofcompany3+"&datefrom1="+datefrom1+"&datefrom2="+datefrom2+"&datefrom3="+datefrom3+"&dateto1="+dateto1+"&dateto2="+dateto2+"&dateto3="+dateto3+"&position1="+position1+"&position2="+position2+"&position3="+position3+"&titleofcourse1="+titleofcourse1+"&titleofcourse2="+titleofcourse2+"&titleofcourse3="+titleofcourse3+"&yeartaken1="+yeartaken1+"&yeartaken2="+yeartaken2+"&yeartaken3="+yeartaken3+"&trainingcenter1="+trainingcenter1+"&trainingcenter2="+trainingcenter2+"&trainingcenter3="+trainingcenter3+"&certifications1="+certifications1+"&certifications2="+certifications2+"&certifications3="+certifications3+"&cashamount="+cashamount+"&charge="+charge+"&modeofpayment="+modeofpayment+"&tuition="+tuition+"&balance="+balance+"&card="+card+"&cardtype="+cardtype+"&card_amount="+card_amount+"&appr_code="+appr_code+"&bank="+bank+"&check_no="+check_no+"&checkamount="+checkamount+"&hidden="+hidden+"&hidden2="+hidden2+"&hidden3="+hidden3+"&id="+id,
    type: 'POST',
    data: formData,
    async: false,
    success: function (data) {
    $('#info2').html(data);
    viewdata(); 
    },
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false
});

return false;}
```